# How to use multiple find commands in the for loop in batch?

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, find

I have the following code:

```
set "string_pdf=<module>PDF-hul</module>"
set string1=Well-Formed and valid
set /a loop100=0

for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('dir /a-d /b /s %output%') do (
    for /f "tokens=3 delims=>/<" %%p in ('find  "%string_pdf%" "%%i" && find "%string1%" "%%i" ') do (
        echo %%~ni >> %output%\pdf_hul.txt
        set /a loop100+=1
    )
)
```

I'm going through all XML's that are located in the `%output%` folder and trying to find the co-occurrence of  `Well-Formed and valid` and `<module>PDF-hul</module>`  in one xml file. This code works when I'm searching only with one find command for one variable. But when I add the second one I get a syntactical error.

How to find both variables `string_pdf` and `string1` in one xml (aren't in one line)?

Comment: You have to escape the `&&` --> `^&^&`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to escape the `&&` --> `^&^&` but
IMO the 2nd for isn't neccessary simply use a findstr with two strings and
a conditional execution on success `&&` and suppress any output of the findstr

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\11\01\SO_53102597.cmd
@Echo off
set output=X:\Path
set "string_pdf=<module>PDF-hul</module>"
set string1=Well-Formed and valid
set /a loop100=0

for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('dir /a-d /b /s "%output%*.xml"') do (
    findstr /IM /c:"%string_pdf%" "%%i" >NUL 2>&1 && (
        findstr /IM /c:"%string1%" "%%i" >NUL 2>&1 && (
            echo %%~ni >> %output%\pdf_hul.txt
            set /a loop100+=1
        )
    )
)
set loop
```

Comment: That works for one counter loop100. But if I want to count additionally the coccurrence  of e.g. string_pdf and string2 I use the counter loop200 and copy (
    findstr /c:"%string_pdf%" /c:"%string2%" "%%i" >NUL 2>&1 && (
        echo %%~ni >> %output%\pdf_hul.txt
        set /a loop200+=1
    )     In this case the counters don't work correct.

Comment: ATM the co-occurence is counted, to count them individually you'd need separate findstr only incrementing the one occurence.

Comment: I don't understand how do you mean to separate them?

Comment: As I understand I can't count co-occurrences individually using only one counter

Comment: You can't but within one for loop you could have multiple findstr counting with it's own counters.

Comment: I always get the wrong counter result when counting the co-occurence of string_pdf and string1. The counter result is correct when I'm using only one search argument (string_pdf or string1) in findstr.

Comment: You are right, I revised the code, please check it out. One error was no extension on the dir, and the findstr has to be nested otherwise it's an or not a and codition.

Comment: It works. But we don't need extension on the dir. %output% is a directory with xml's inside that should be processed

Comment: But the output txt file goes to the same dir and without extension is also processed `%output%\pdf_hul.txt` on successive runs.